# Tronxy X5SA not working properly after Marlin firmware installation

Tags: marlin, bed-leveling, firmware, z-probe, tronxy-x5sa

Yesterday I installed Marlin firmware, 2.0.x bugfix version on my Tronxy X5SA (v6).

I did it in the way explained on GitHub, with Visual Studio Code, Platform IO, Marlin auto build. I applied the recommended modifications in the Tronxy example.

The firmware compiled successfully (the bugfix sources as the 2.0.9.1 source gives me an error - I may open another question for it), and is starting successfully on the printer. But, I have these 2 issues:

1. When the printer starts, the bed stays in a low position (about 20 cm from the nozzle) and I cannot get it lifted up to reach the Z sensor. When I want to lift it up, I can only lift it by 10 units, then it's on 0.00 and it does not move up anymore. I was used to doing the Z offset manually with the Tronxy firmware, by lifting the bed with the firmware tool. Here, I cannot do it. When reaching 0.00 it does not move up. I could not identify a parameter for it in the config file and/or tutorial.
2. I tried to start a print, nothing happened. Even the nozzle/bed warmup didn't work, nothing was heating up. I tried manually to enable bed/nozzle heating, and it worked.
3. Home position setting. Seems the home position is not correct with X-axis, despite the fact that I did set the printer dimensions in the file. How do I fix it?

As you probably already understood I cannot get anything to work properly so far with my printer and Marlin.

Maybe one of you already faced the same situation with that printer and Marlin, or you might maybe know a good place where I can find a tutorial matching my setup that I can apply the same. So far I was not able to find a thread helping me to get this fixed.

---

I downloaded the file corresponding to X5SA from GitHub, `configuration.h`, and used it. I just applied the recommended changes from [the page of X5SA example](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/blob/bugfix-2.0.x/config/examples/Tronxy/X5SA/HOWTO-INSTALL.md) (with the calculation) to it.

The reason why I used the bugfix source is that I was not able to compile version 2.0.9.1. It ends up with an error message I was not able to fix. Only the bugfix version did compile.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sounds like you need to home the printer, otherwise, it has no way of knowing, where the actual "zero coordinate" is. The printer will "never" go beyond 0 for safety reasons.
2. Do you have the cables plugged into the correct ports on the motherboard?
3. What do you mean by "home position is not correct"? Bed dimensions have no influence on homing since homing put the printer to XYZ 000. And zero is always on the endstop.

Also, if you can post your config - `Configuration.h` and `Configuration_adv.h`, it would be helpful.